# expected unqualified-id before 'public' - fail to see the problem (Java)

Tags: java, function, class

I spent around 4, maybe 5 hours trying to figure out this chunk of code from the java site yesterday. It takes a hexadecimal input and converts it into a digit. There were a lot of methods I hadn't yet explored. But after finally wrapping my head around it (shoutouts to "birdfreeyahoo"), I tried throwing it into my program and compiling. And then I ran into this error:

expected unqualified-id before 'public'

I've made and called void functions before but I've never dealt with classes or static functions yet. Most tutorials I've been following just rely on coding purely within the setup or loop scopes because arduino is geared toward beginners. As birdfreeyahoo mentioned, getDecimal(String hex) has to be declared at the beginning of the function so that property String hex can be called later in the program for use.

I know it has to be something related to the syntax of the class/function in the program, since I copied the code from the java site and is 1:1 verbatum (of course only after breaking it down and analyzing it first).

Code:

```
public class HexToDecimalExample3{    
public static int getDecimal(String hex){   
    String digits = "0123456789ABCDEF";  
             hex = hex.toUpperCase();  
             int val = 0;  
             for (int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i++)  
             {  
                 char c = hex.charAt(i);  
                 int d = digits.indexOf(c);  
                 val = 16*val + d;  
             }  
             return val;  
            }
          }
```

This was thrown alongside my other simpler functions in the program and implemented before void setup(){}

For the entirety of my program and where it stands as of right now (for reference):

//Because of the LED provided in the kit, we are forced to use some work-arounds to get the RGB working for a Common Anode LED. The original lesson material was directed for a Common Cathode.

```
class test{
    public static void main(string[] args){

          int LEDPower = 8;
          int redPin = 6;
          int greenPin = 5;
          int bluePin = 3;
          int voltInput;
          String colorChoice;

          //FUNCTIONS FOR SIMPLER IMPLIMENTATION

          void redColor (){
            analogWrite (redPin, 0);
            analogWrite (greenPin, 255);
            analogWrite (bluePin, 255);
          }

          void greenColor (){
            analogWrite (redPin, 255);
            analogWrite (greenPin, 0);
            analogWrite (bluePin, 255);
            }

          void blueColor (){
            analogWrite (redPin, 255);
            analogWrite (greenPin, 255);
            analogWrite (bluePin, 0);
            }


          public class HexToDecimalExample3{    
          public static int getDecimal(String hex){   
              String digits = "0123456789ABCDEF";  
                       hex = hex.toUpperCase();  
                       int val = 0;  
                       for (int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i++)  
                       {  
                           char c = hex.charAt(i);  
                           int d = digits.indexOf(c);  
                           val = 16*val + d;  
                       }  
                       return val;  
                      }
                    }


          void setup() {
            Serial.begin (2000000);
            pinMode (LEDPower, OUTPUT);
            pinMode (redPin, OUTPUT);
            pinMode (greenPin, OUTPUT);
            pinMode (bluePin, OUTPUT);
            digitalWrite (LEDPower, HIGH);

          }


            /*
            for (int j=1; j<3; j+1){
              redColor();
              delay(100);
              greenColor();
              delay(100);
              blueColor();
              delay(100);
            }
            */

          }



          void loop() {

            Serial.println("What Color Would You Like (HEX COLORS #RRGGBB)?");
            while (Serial.available()==0);{
            }
            colorChoice = Serial.readString();
            colorChoice.trim();
            Serial.println("Decimal of " + colorChoice + "is: " +getDecimal(colorChoice));



            if (colorChoice=="red"){
              redColor();
            }

            if (colorChoice=="green"){
              greenColor();
            }

            if (colorChoice=="blue"){
              blueColor();    
            }





            //THROW EXCEPTION IF NOT VALID

          /*
            if (colorChoice != "red" && colorChoice != "green" && colorChoice!= "blue"){
              Serial.println("");
              Serial.println("That is not a valid choice");
              Serial.println("");
            }
            */

          /*
            if (strstr(colorChoice, "red") != NULL){
              Serial.println("applying...");
              delay(1000);
              analogWrite (redPin, 0);
              analogWrite (greenPin, 255);
              analogWrite (bluePin, 255);
            }
          */

          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Do you have methods outside a class? Methods are always contained in a class in Java, and the name of the file has to match the name of the class.

Comment: If that is truly your entirety of your program, you will need to place the code (blueColor, etc.) in class. Also, you need an entry point; that is a "main" method. I would recommend placing HexToDecimalExample in its own file, and either placing the rest of your program in the "entry" class (the one with a "main" method), or a separate class which you can import in the class with the entry point. I am a bit confused with your program through; for example, where is analogwrite() defined?

Comment: I'm using the arduino IDE and a single script so far. There hasn't ever been any mention within my tutorial series about a Main class or other things that have come up when looking into this issue and googling around. I've also tried throwing the entirety of the program into a "void Main(){}" but still ran into compiling errors.

Comment: @Aspen, I don't know much about Arduino, but in Java everything except for import and package statements (and some annotations) are defined within a class body. The "main" method is defined in a class, not the other way around. The tutorials from Oracle are a nice introduction for starting with Java:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: Ok let me try adding a Main method and see where it goes real quick. The analogWrite() is within the void color functions toward the top of the program. The idea was to call 3 simple colors (red, green blue) more easily as a start since common anode LED's are inverted and harder to impliment than a common cathode. It was just a work-around. I plan to code an algorithm that will dynamically add analog voltage to the 3 pins based on the hex number.

Comment: @KellyMarchewa Alright Kelly.. I added the class 'test' and a main method based off a beginner tutorial example. However I'm still getting a compiling error. expected ':' before 'static' Based on the example, this syntax looks correct. No?

You can see the example in the updated "where my program stands now" section

Comment: I was just informed on the arduino forums that arduino uses C++ and not java. Even though all the examples I've googled for the arduino show java methods and language. They must be similar.. Crap.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have copy-and-pasted the entire `HexToDecimalExample3` class into the middle of the `main` method.

That is not valid.  You cannot embed a public class in the middle of a method like that.

Go back to your Java textbook or tutorial and read about the structure of a Java class, how to declare methods, how to call methods and so on.  That will help you understand what you should be doing.

Here is a good place to start learning:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

---

Hint: put the getDecimal method **before** the main method, and get rid of the spurious `HexToDecimalExample3` class declaration.